# Existence of certain subgroup of non-abelian group of order $p^3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^3$, where $p$ is prime, and $G$ is not abelian.  Let $Z$ be its center. Suppose $x^p=1$ for all $x\in G$. Show that $G$ contains a normal subgroup $H\cong \mathbb{Z}_p\times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

**Remark:** I have tried but many different approaches to this problem but I failed. Also we are not allow to use any structure theorem. Here it is one of my approaches.

Since $x^p=1$ for all $x\in G$ then all non-identity elements in $G$ has order $p$. Take some $x\neq e\in G$ and consider the subgroup $\langle x\rangle_p$ of $G$. Let's take $y\in G-\langle x\rangle_p$ then we see that $\langle x\rangle_p\cap \langle y\rangle_p=\{e\}$ and $\langle x\rangle_p, \langle y\rangle_p\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$. I was trying to show that these subgroups are normal but no results.

So I would be very grateful if anyone can show how to solve this problem?

Comment: Prove that $Z(G)$ has order $p$.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of user10354138 gives the correct idea. 
$Z(G)$ is non-trivial because $G$ is a $p$-group, so it has order $p$ or $p^2$ ($G$ is not abelian). If it has order $p^2$, then $G/Z(G)$ would have order $p$, and so would be cyclic. It is a standard fact that this implies that $G$ is cyclic, which we excluded. Hence $Z(G)$ has order $p$, call $x$ a generator. Now take any element $y$ not in the center. If $y$ has order $p$ then $<x,y>\cong \mathbb Z/p\times\mathbb Z/p$, otherwise $y$ has order $p^2$, and $<x,y^p>$ does the trick.

To make this problem more concrete, let me tell you that there is in fact only one group (for any odd prime $p$) with those characteristics.

First of all, if $p=2$ then $x^2=1$ for every $x$, so $G$ is abelian, so assume $p$ odd.

The group $G$ is the so-called Heisenberg group. It consists of upper triangular $3\times 3$ matrices with diagonal entries all equal to $1$.